# getting all dynamically created linearlayout android java

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

```
ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) v.findViewById(R.id.layout_question_content);
LinearLayout layout_questions = (LinearLayout) sv.findViewWithTag("layout_questions");
int childcount = layout_questions.getChildCount();
System.out.println("LinearLayout " + childcount);
```

I want to get All Linear Layout using tag but I get

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.ScrollView.findViewWithTag(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

All my LinearLayout including all its child are dynamically added

`XML`

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/layout_question_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50px"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Your `sv` is `null`. Care to share your XML?

Comment: You sure you got the Scrollview ID correctly?

Comment: Where are you writing this snippet inside onCreate() ? or somewhere else ? The ScrollView is not initialised. It will throw a null object reference.
Share the method in which you have written this, also share the xml.

Comment: i have another declaration `ScrollView sv = (ScrollView) v.findViewById(R.id.layout_question_content);` this declaration i get an error. So what i did is declare it again. This is the scroll view where i add the view into

Comment: Again, please update your answer with the XML file you're using. Without it, everyone here could only play a guessing game rather than giving an actual, working answer.

Comment: @HadiSatrio sorry i dont have xml because i add them dynamically but i will add the scroll view

Comment: That's what everyone's talking about: The ScrollView's XML. Okay, this looks good. Now, how did you inflate this XML? The problem might lies there.

Comment: @HadiSatrio i have `View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_questionnaire, null);` then i have `setContentView(v);`

Answer (score 0):

The `ScrollView` is either not defined in your XML or your `<ScrollView />` does not have the id `layout_question_content`. Check that you have `android:id="@+id/layout_question_content"` set.